# Connectivity Check not Working in Android Oreo Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-8.0-oreo, kotlin-android-extensions

Trying to call the broadcast receiver called NetworkReceiver on network change. The same code in java works but doesn't work when trying to do it in Kotlin. The receiver is never called when the connection happens or when it is lost. Im trying to do it in emulator. Also the receiver isn't called when the boot is completed. Also Im testing this on Android Oreo i.e. Android 8.0

> ```
> NetworkReceiver.kt
> ```

```
class NetworkReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

                override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                    Logs.v("onReceive")
                    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
                    val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
                    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.detailedState == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED) {
                        Logs.v("Network Connected")

                    } else if (networkInfo != null) {
                        val state = networkInfo.detailedState
                        Logs.v("NetworkReceiver", state.name)
                    } else {
                        Logs.v("Network Connected")
                    }
                }
            }
```

> Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.android.client">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:name=".application.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver android:name=".network.NetworkReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".views.activities.kt.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".views.activities.kt.DashboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity android:name=".views.activities.kt.ConfigurationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_configuration"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Oreo, broadcast receiver behavior has changed, it is much more restricted. I am surprised that you say "it works in java".

Regardless, you will need to [read up](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html) on the "Oreo" changes.  And a couple things are missing from your app.  You need to set `android:enabled="true"` in the manifest on your receiver and you need to call...

```
registerReceiver(MyNetworkReceiver(), IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"))`
```

... from your app (probably in onCreate) to receive connection state changes while your app is running (it will also fire at app startup).  You may also need to set `android:export="true"` in the manifest (for receiving broadcasts from whitelist actions).

Comment: Thanks,I am using java. After registering It works fine for me.

Comment: Hi, What happened if the app is not running? The reason why I want broadcast receiver on android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED, it's because I want to start the service when the wifi state changes when the app is not running. Thanks.

Comment: @sgon00 - setting the flags in the manifest is the pre-Oreo way to let the system know to start your app on the given event.  The changes in Oreo were made they say to prevent abuses of the broadcast receiver and conserve battery.  See [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) which suggests that you use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) instead.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need this permission for listening to boot completed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Try to declare your broadcast receiver in the manifest at this way:

```
<receiver android:name=".network.NetworkReceiver"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
           <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```